Why is modal logic not focused more on strict implication?
Modal logic is designed to capture various notions, such as necessity, time, provability, etc. These notions are captured via a box operator or sometimes the letter L.
For example, in systems capable of expressing necessity, □A means “A is necessary.”
C.I. Lewis was one of the first to modernize modal logic, and he used strict implication heavily in his systems. He was very interested in figuring out the correct system of strict implication, which helped to produce many well-known logics like T, S4, and S5.
Is there a specific historical or philosophical reason that the use of strict implication in particular has fallen by the wayside since Lewis’s time?

Is there any application for the strict implication in answering a serious philosophical question outside of modal logic?

That seems to be the whole point. We can use modal logic to model different kinds of speech modalities, not just truth. Besides, most people would agree that strict implications are at least better at modeling human reasoning than classical implication does.

Just modeling speech modalities is not necessarily a serious philosophical question. That could just be linguistics, unless the speech modalities are about some deep philosophical question like consciousness or morality.

Did you read the post?

The historical and philosophical reason is that Kripke's possible worlds semantics is much more flexible and easier to adapt to various concerns that philosophers have than formal systems with shifty semantics, especially those tied to a specific conditional. Btw, you probably mean C.I. Lewis, not David.

Some logicians such as Grice used conversational implicature to argue that despite apparent difficulties material conditional is just fine for natural languages. Some logicians have noted that the strict conditional cannot adequately express counterfactual conditionals which are context dependent and non-monotonic, Stalnaker's variably strict conditionals try to address these issues. Others turned to relevance logic to supply a connection between the antecedent and consequent of provable conditionals or structural equations to model causal counterfactual conditions for individuals across PW...

C.I.Lewis' theory of strict implication is based on the criticism of Pricipia's supposed lack of distinction between the conditional connective and the relation of logical consequence. But in a nutshell strict implcation fails to make a distinction between the necessity of a conditional and logical consequence.

C I Lewis developed modal logic in a series of papers starting in the 1910s. His main motivation was to introduce a strict conditional that accurately captures the meaning of logical consequence. This was a response to the fact that the material implication connective defined in Principia Mathematica is just a truth function. When we speak of logical consequence, it is natural to use modal language. We might say that if the premises of a valid argument are true then the conclusion necessarily follows. Or that it is impossible for the premises to be true and the conclusion false. Material implication lacks this modal force. It is suitable for expressing non-modal sufficient condition relations, but not for expressing logical consequence.
Lewis himself initially thought that the strict conditonal of S3 did the job, then he changed his mind to S2. Curiously, this seems to be because he didn't think logical consequence is transitive. Today, it is more common to regard S4 as doing the job of expressing consequence. Or K4W if we wish to talk about provability within a formal system without assuming soundness and using finitistic proofs.
But Lewis' original motivation was overtaken by developments in proof theory and model theory. Proof theory provides a way to account for logical consequence in terms of formal deductive systems. Model theory provides a way of describing logical consequence in terms of truth preservation under all interpretations. There are many other options also. I listed the main ones in my answer to this question.
Although the original motivation of understanding logical consequence was no longer salient, modal logics proved to be a useful way to express modal flavours such as necessity, obligation, knowledge, belief, etc. Philosophers like to reason about such things and so they adopted the study of modal logics. Mathematicians and linguists did too. Kripke, von Wright and Hintikka came along later and supplied the possible world semantics.
In recent years, strict implication is more commonly studied as an option for understanding the meaning of conditionals. Real world uses of conditionals nearly always have some modal flavour, whether express or implied, so the material implication does a poor job of representing their meaning correctly. Lots of work has been done in this area and there are many theories of conditionals though no general consensus on the best way to represent them. There are some people defending the thesis that all conditionals are strict implications, though my impression is that this is not a popular option.

Thank you for your detailed answer. Is there any substance to whether or not formal, finitistic consequence is preferable to the consequence captured by S4?

@PW_246 Modal logic S4 is nothing but classical propositional logic plus the modal axioms □ϕ → ϕ , □ϕ → □□ϕ, and (ϕ→ψ) → (□ϕ→□ψ) (IIRC for a highly sketched proof see an old post's answer about S4 in this site), thus it's not any more preferable for most mathematics purposes which are non-modal in their nature except perhaps in cases involving interior operations of topological spaces or algebras with open sets where extensivity, idempotency and monotonicity are all important...

@DoubleKnot isn’t it □(P→Q) →(□P→□Q)? Or are you using → for strict implication?

@PW_246 absolutely you're careful enough, I just copied and pasted from the linked highly sketched 'proof', of course your pointed out K axiom is the true monotonicity...

S4 also includes the necessitation rule.
